# How to stop hyperledger composer playground running on localhost from ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-composer, ubuntu-18.04

I can start the composer playground by writing `composer-playground` to ubuntu terminal but how can I stop the composer playground? The terminal looks like below when I start the composer playground and no terminal command works.
[image: ubuntu terminal screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the composer playground by simple pressing **`ctrl + c`** on ubuntu or **`Command(⌘) + c`** on mac.